Doubt in Relation between Ka and Kb of conjugate acid base pair

In the derivation shown in this image, how did they equate the product of Ka and Kb with Kw? I see that they replaced the [H][OH] with (Ka)[h2o] Or (Kb)[h2o]. But I don't understand how.
The [H] in the equation is for the conc of H+ at the equilibrium of HCOOH ionisation.
The [OH] in the equation is for the conc of OH- at the equilibrium of HCOO- ionisation.
How did the product of these two, become equal to [H][OH] at equilibrium of water self ionisation? Or is there some logic of simultaneous equilibrium involved?
I have just started studying ionic equilibrium (high school class), and this was causing a lot of confusion later on.
Thanks for your precious time.

They enumerated both constants in the multiple Ka x Kb and eliminated the same terms in the nominator and denominator, obtaining Kw. And yes, both, or rather all three equilibrii are simulataneous. You can also show that Ka=Kw/Kb = ([H+][OH-])/([HA][OH-]/[A-])=[H+][A-]/[HA]

Search also about the topic, namely this site and chem.libretexts.org.

Alright, all three of them being simultaneous makes this a lot more clear. I will read further.
